# Problemas con la pseudo-clase Hover

Tags: css

¡Buen día! soy nuevo en la programación con css y estoy tratando de usar el :hover  y pasa esto...

[image]

el :hover no se activa cuando lo coloco para hacer un boton o algo por el estilo, espero puedan ayudarme, mucha gracias por su atención.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El problema es que trato de usar la pseudo-clase,para realizar un botón en un enlace, pero no hace nada y ni siquiera el código :hover cambia de color (como se ve en la imagen)

Comment: Acabo de colocar la hoja de código

Comment: @maranwind Copia y pega el codigo en la publicaicon.. eso es lo que quiere decir BetaM

Comment: a :hover { text-decoration:underline ;
    background: white;
 }

Answer (score 0):

Elimina el espacio entre el `a:` y `hover`

```
es
a:hover {}
no 
a: hover {}
```

Answer (score 0):

en efecto debes eliminar el espacio
debe ser así:

```
a:hover {
}
```

y si quieres modificar su tamaño es necesario ponerle
un display ya sea `display: flex`o `display: inline-block`